# Phrase suggestor - which index and query to act upon

Tags: elasticsearch

How does this query know which index and document type to act on? I can't seem to see any reference to an index or a type.

```
curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/_search' -d {
  "suggest" : {
    "text" : "Xor the Got-Jewel",
    "simple_phrase" : {
      "phrase" : {
        "analyzer" : "body",
        "field" : "bigram",
        "size" : 1,
        "real_word_error_likelihood" : 0.95,
        "max_errors" : 0.5,
        "gram_size" : 2,
        "direct_generator" : [{
            "field" : "body",
            "suggest_mode" : "always",
            "min_word_length" : 1
          }
        ],
        "highlight" : {
          "pre_tag" : "<em>",
          "post_tag" : "</em>"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're not specifying index in your search request, for instance:

```
curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/your_index/_search
```

It's going to run your query against all possible indices.

From [Search API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.4/search-search.html#search-search) documentation:

> All search APIs can be applied across multiple types within an index,
>   and across multiple indices with support for the multi index syntax.
>   For example, we can search on all documents across all types within
>   the twitter index:
>
> ```
> $ curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/twitter/_search?q=user:kimchy'
> ```
>
> We can also search within specific types:
>
> ```
> $ curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/twitter/tweet,user/_search?q=user:kimchy'
> ```
>
> We can also search all tweets with a certain tag across several
>   indices (for example, when each user has his own index):
>
> ```
> $ curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/kimchy,elasticsearch/tweet/_search?q=tag:wow'
> ```
>
> Or we can search all tweets across all available indices using _all
>   placeholder:
>
> ```
> $ curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/_all/tweet/_search?q=tag:wow'
> ```
>
> Or even search across all indices and all types:
>
> ```
> $ curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/_search?q=tag:wow'
> ```